# Allowing users to build views from my database and editing those fields

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm building a site that contains "panels" which are used as containers for various information. I have set it up so panels are editable, which is simple for panels that just contain text. For that I just grab the content from the database and wrap it in a textarea rather than a `<p>` tag. For panels that contain table views however this is proving to be a more difficult task.

First off I'm having trouble allowing the admin of the site pick what information is in a given table (for example if the admin wanted to add a panel view that showed each members first name, last name, and picture they could pick from those columns in my database). I've come up with a few ways to do this, but each have their own set of problems.

I tried using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table to generate a table containing the possible tables and columns that the user can choose from. But when it comes to building the query with PDO I have problems. For instance with prepared statements you can't use a variable for the schema.

I also thought of using MySQL views but I can't seem to figure out how to do it that way either.

My second problem is allowing the admin to add rows to the tables directly. Right now all the add row template does is create a row with a text field in each column. This is good for purely text options (like first name) but for things like pictures obviously a text field won't work. Should I create a table that contains this metadata or perform the check in PHP? If it's the latter, how would I know what input type the column needs?

I think my main problem is I'm trying to solve too many things with only one design change (or not focusing on one problem at a time). It's resulting in me becoming very flustered and confused. Help is greatly appreciated and if you need anymore information like how my database tables are currently setup I'll provide an ERD.

**Edit:** I just wanted to make it clear that I don't want to allow the user to actually manipulate the tables in the database, but rather select what information from the existing tables is shown on a given panel.

Answer (score 1):

Coding the ability for users to freely query a database has a lot of problems (including security) and is way more complicated than predefined information queries that simply return a defined set of information.

It also places the burden of defining which info might be useful onto the user. It places the burden of deciding whether a certain information should be accessible to a particular user onto the query logic and database access rules.

Effectively you are trying to copy PHPMyAdmin with a different design and only your defined database as a target.

Comment: Essentially, yes, I am copying what PHPMyAdmin does. I am understanding how difficult it is to allow the user to freely create views from a database. I had planned on having drop down boxes that contained all the columns the user can choose from to lower the security risks (although no where near secure). I had also planned on checking the values returned to the server against a table containing all the viable column names. Anyway, I would really like to achieve this goal so someone without programming experience can still add content to the site.

Comment: Someone without programming experience will never ever be able to handle a database. Even those WITH programming experience often fail properly handling a database. If you will ever stand a chance of someone adding some content, hide the fact that there is a database. Have a look at successful websites that allow users to add content: Wikipedia, Stackoverflow... a database is nowhere to be seen. But even the tiny bit of "formatting text" usually is demanding way too much from the average user. You should re-focus your scope and your goals, or nobody will use it because its too complicated.

Comment: I don't want them to literally work with the database. I'm not planning on allowing the user to create actual tables or add fields to existing tables. All I'm trying to do is allow the user to decide what fields are shown on different panels. For example for a view with users you may only want to show there first and last name, but for a different view you may want to display their email too. I don't think that will be too difficult but I can't speak for people without programming experience, so I could be wrong.